# Alternativa3D: Remove black background, and make it transparent

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d

Hi I'm dealing with alternativa3D, I need to remove the black background of the scene3D,

with the objective of put a camera layer on the background, to emulate augmented reality.

This is simply: Some 3D objects appears over the camera layer.

Some idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to make Stage3D background transparent. You should render your video to a texture using Stage3D API and then place your augmented reality overlay on the top of the geometry where video is rendered.

Comment: SOLUTION: http://www.ar-forum.ru/viewtopic.php?id=9 and http://www.ar-forum.ru/viewtopic.php?id=12